# If I use explicit constructor, do I need to put the keyword in both .h and .cpp files?

Tags: c++, explicit-constructor

Actually my question is all in the title.
Anyway:
I have a class and I use explicit constructor:

.h

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    explicit MyClass(const string& s): query(s) {}
  private:
   string query;
}
```

Is it obligatory or not to put **explicit** keyword in implementation(.cpp) file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, it is not. The `explicit` keyword is only permitted in the header. My gcc says:

```
test.cpp:6: error: only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'
```

for the following code:

```
class foo {
public:
    explicit foo(int);
};

explicit foo::foo(int) {}
```

Comment: I understood what he meant... I simply read the line in between.

Comment: My MS VC++ (2012) says: 'test.cpp(6): error C2071: foo::{ctor} : illegal storage class'

Answer (score 0):

Re the followup question (which you really should have submitted as a separate question), the initialization list goes with the constructor's implementation (its function body), which might be in either the header or the cpp file.